# How can I send "<asp:datalist>" content with c# to an email?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, data-binding

So I have this problem :
I have my Datalist on asp.net, but i don't know how to retrive the data for sending it to an email. I have tried appending it on a string but I think it's not the solution. 
Can someone help me please?

```
<asp:DataList ID="listaSuper" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="listaSuper_ItemDataBound"                  
              Width="100%" RepeatColumns="1" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
              DataKeyNames="IdListaSuperDetalle"
              OnItemCommand="DataList_projects_ItemCommand">
 <ItemTemplate>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Image ID="Image3" Style="width: 200px; height: 200px" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("UrlImg", "{0}") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="sCursos" style="padding: 5px 0 0 5px;">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 40px; padding: 4px;">
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IdListaSuperDetalle") %>'
                                    ImageUrl="~/images/LstSuper/tache.png" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Receta")%>'></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblreceta" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IdReceta")%>'
                                    Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="sCursos" style="padding: 5px 0 0 5px;">
                    <br />
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DataList ID="listaSuperdd" runat="server" DataKeyField="Idreceta">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <table style="width: 100%; margin-left: 10%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="width: 40px; padding: 4px;">
                                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkIngredientes" runat="server" Checked="true" />
                                                </td>
                                                <td align="left">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Descripcion")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="width: 20px; padding: 4px;">
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:DataList>
                                <br />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

And my C# code is this:

Note that I'm not sending anything from the datalist because I don't know how I can make it... And in this moment I'm frustrated... so here it is:

```
protected void EnviarCorreo(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Id"]);

    EntCheft Chef = new EntCheft();

    if (Session["User"] != null)
    {
        Chef = Session["User"] as EntCheft;

        LyncottClient objCliente = new LyncottClient();
        WsLyncott.EntCheft Resultado = new WsLyncott.EntCheft();
        Resultado = Session["User"] as WsLyncott.EntCheft;

        string sNombre = string.Format("{0} {1}", Chef.Nombre, Chef.ApellidoP);
        MailAddress ToMail = new MailAddress(Resultado.Email, sNombre);
        cCorreo CorreoRegistro = new cCorreo();

        var txtMsgReceta = new StringBuilder();
        divmensaje.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(txtMsgReceta)));

        string s = txtMsgReceta.ToString();
        txtMsgReceta.Append("<html><head><title></title></head><body style='background-color:White'>")
            .Append("<table border='0'> <tr> <td style='width: 70%;'><img src='../images/impReceta/hoja-impresion_01.jpg' width='199' height='112'/> </td>")
             .Append("<td align='right'>")
             .Append("MI LISTA DE SUPER")
             .Append("<br /> </td></tr>")
             .Append(" <tr> </tr></table>")
             .Append("<table><tr><td>  <img src='../images/impReceta/hoja-impresion_24.jpg' width='645' height='28' /> </td> </tr></table></body>");



        CorreoRegistro.EnviarCorreoLocal(ToMail, sNombre, Resultado.Email,txtMsgReceta, "Receta..");

    }
    Response.Redirect("LstSuper.aspx");
}

   public string SendMailPruebalocal(string Subject, MailAddress ToMailAddress, MailAddress FromMailAddress, string Body)
{


    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    msg.From = FromMailAddress;

    msg.To.Add(ToMailAddress); 
    //msg.Bcc.Add("contacto@*****.com");
    msg.Subject = Subject;//Asunto
    msg.Body = Body;  //Cuerpo del correo
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    msg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();

    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("******", "*****");
    SmtpServer.Port = 587;
    SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
    try
    {
        SmtpServer.Send(msg);
        msg.Dispose();
        return "Se envio la información correctamente.";

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }


}



public void EnviarCorreoLocal(MailAddress ToMail, string sNombre, string User, StringBuilder txtMsgReceta, string titulo)
{
    MailAddress FromMail = new MailAddress("contacto@*****.com", "*********");
    SendMailPruebalocal(titulo, ToMail, FromMail, txtMsgReceta.ToString());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the data inside the DataList into HTML, you can't simply just add it. Luckily, this is easy enough using `HtmlTextWriter` and the web control's `RenderControl` method.

```
var htmlTxtWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(new System.IO.StringWriter(txtMsgReceta , System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

listaSuperdd.RenderControl(htmlTxtWriter);
```